# install templates in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

when I want to install template with laravel mix,I see this error and javascript files dont mix properly

```
 at Parser.raise (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7013:17)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9188:16)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9067:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9040:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9000:21)
    at Parser.parseConditional (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9056:29)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9047:17)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9000:21)
    at Parser.parseExpression (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8950:23)
    at Parser.parseReturnStatement (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11027:28)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10706:21)
    at Parser.parseStatement (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10658:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\xampp\htdocs\temp.test\blog\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:1123
4:25)
```

What can I do?

Comment: You've left off the important bit of the error message, and it's unclear what you mean by "install template". Laravel doesn't inherently have templates that you'd "install" (and Blade templates don't typically go through Mix), so you need to give us some more info.

Comment: I want to mix all css files and javascript files from a html template @ceejayoz

Comment: The first bit of my comment still applies; you need to show us the error. There should be an error message somewhere before the bit you've quoted.